# Why don't these two wordpress php blocks work out the same?

Tags: php, wordpress

This first bit works:

```
                $my_id = 617;
                $post_id_7 = get_post($my_id); 
                $title = $post_id_7->post_excerpt;
                echo $title;
```

While this second bit doesn't:

```
                $post_id_7 = get_post(617); 
                $title = $post_id_7->post_excerpt;
                echo $title;
```

What gives?

Comment: Also, in the title I think you mean "Why *don't* these two ... "

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post

> You must pass a variable containing an integer (e.g. $id). A literal integer (e.g. 7) will cause a fatal error

Answer (score 1):

yeah what Samuel said.

So if you wrote it:

```
$post_id_7 = get_post('617');  
$title = $post_id_7->post_excerpt; 
echo $title;
```

it should work.

Comment: That would just pass a string. The get_post parameter is passed by reference so you MUST pass a variable and not a literal value.